# Retorno JSON em um array no LOOP

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Estou precisando guardar o retorno do `JSON` em um array, ou seja:

```
                        $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        dataType: "json",
                        url: "/engine/listarPublicacoes.php", 
                        success: function(data) {
                            for (var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
                                var availableTags = [
                                      {label:data[i+1], the_link:'http://intranet.supersoft.com.br/publicacao/'+data[i]+''}
                                ];
                                $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
                                    source: availableTags,
                                    select:function(e,ui) { 
                                        window.location.href = ui.item.the_link;
                                    }
                                }); 
                            }   
                        }
                    });
```

a variavel `availableTags` precisa guardar as minhas informações, mas como eu posso colocar ela no loop para cada info, ter seu objeto? meu json segue assim:

```
["79","ADIANTAMENTO DE 13. SALARIO EM 26\/11\/14","78",null,"77",null,"76",null,"74",null,"73",null,"72","SS News NOV\/DEZ","71",null,"70","Facebook desenvolve rede social profissional ","69",null,"68","6 dicas para proteger dados no Whatsapp","61",null,"60",null,"59","Os ensinamentos de Martha Gabriel para o marketing na era digital","58","Pensamento do dia","57",null,"56","Gente que vira marca: o que aprender com o marketing das celebridades"]
```

Comment: Depois de 48 perguntas, os editores não deviam ter que ficar removendo o ruido dos seus posts. Por favor, confira as edições que são feitas nas suas perguntas para não ficar repetindo *sempre* os mesmos erros. Obrigado.

Comment: @brasofilo me desculpe, é que as vezes eu não consigo me expressar direito, vou prestar mais atenção nas perguntas, obrigado!

Comment: @Furlan você pode votar nas respostas que te ajudaram também. Qualquer resposta (ou mesmo pergunta) do *site* que de alguma aforma te ajudaram ou você acha que ajudariam outras pessoas. Especialmente seria legal votar em respostas dadas à sua pergunta. O voto é tão ou mais importante em certas circunstâncias que a aceitação.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use o loop para montar a variável, e só depois inicialize o autocomplete:

```
var availableTags = [];

for (var i=0;i<data.length;i+=2){
    availableTags.push({label:data[i+1], the_link:'http://intranet.supersoft.com.br/publicacao/'+data[i]+''});
}  

$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
    source: availableTags,
    select:function(e,ui) { 
        window.location.href = ui.item.the_link;
    }
});
```

A array é criada antes do loop, vazia, e você usa o método [`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) dela para acrescentar novos objetos.

Comment: obrigado @bfavaretto! deu certo!